# Turn off ssl certificate validation for JiraRestClient

Tags: java, rest, ssl-certificate, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I'm trying to connect to my Jira via the atlassian rest api java framework:

```java
JiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
JiraRestClient client = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(uri, userName, password);
```

But this causes a errors:

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem`

`PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

I think this happens because I use a self-signed certificate for my Jira. Is there a way to turn of certificate validation for the `JiraRestClientFactory`  at least for development purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the replies! The solution I ended up with is based on Karol Dowbeckis answer:

```java
    JiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
    HttpClientOptions options = new HttpClientOptions();
    options.setTrustSelfSignedCertificates(true);
    DefaultHttpClientFactory defaultHttpClientFactory = new DefaultHttpClientFactory(new NoOpEventPublisher(),
            new RestClientApplicationProperties(JIRA_URI), new ThreadLocalContextManager() {
        @Override
        public Object getThreadLocalContext() {
            return null;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void setThreadLocalContext(Object context) {
        }
        
        @Override
        public void clearThreadLocalContext() {
        }
    });
    HttpClient httpClient = defaultHttpClientFactory.create(options);

    AtlassianHttpClientDecorator atlassianHttpClientDecorator = new AtlassianHttpClientDecorator(httpClient, new BasicHttpAuthenticationHandler(userName, password)) {
        @Override
        public void destroy() throws Exception {
            defaultHttpClientFactory.dispose(httpClient);
        }
    };
    JiraRestClient client = factory.create(JIRA_URI, atlassianHttpClientDecorator);
```

I had to add my own simple implementations of `NoOpEventPublisher` and `RestClientApplicationProperties` because the atlassian classes are private.

**Additional information for this code sample**

- this example is using the jira rest client version 4.0.0
- `NoOpEventPublisher` is just an implementation of `com.atlassian.event.api.EventPublisher` with empty method bodies.
- `RestClientApplicationProperties` implements `com.atlassian.sal.api.ApplicationProperties` returning my jira url in `getBaseUrl` and "4.0.0" in `getVersion`

Comment: Hi @Sebastian, I'm just curious. Did you add your self signed certificate to the java trust store before asking this question?

Comment: I did not, I searched for a solution without using the trust store.

Comment: Can you please share your code of those 2 classes ?
NoOpEventPublisher and RestClientApplicationProperties

Comment: I adapted my answer and added some information about these classes. They are both quite simple implementations and have a lot of empty method bodies. As the project is two years old, I cannot promise that it still works with never Jira versions.

Comment: Thank you, i tried that, even with version 4.0.0, but getting error:
`SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help you here. My project isn't in use or development anymore. Please open a new question in StackOverflow.

Comment: it will miss the AuthenticationHandler

Answer (score 3):

I know you where looking for a solution without using the trust store. But now your system will trust just any certificate and you will have to disable your workaround when deploying in a productive enviroment.

I recommend suggesting the following solution:

As you noticed - this was caused by your self signed ssl certificate not being registered in the trust store. But instead of trusting all certificates you should just add your self singed certificate to the java trust store. It's easy and fast to resolve.

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -validity #_of_days -keysize 2048 -keystore path_to_keystore_file
```

The default trust store can be found at

```
{JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

You can also create a custom trust store and pass the path as a parameter when starting your application.

More informations and examples on trust stores can be found here:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E54932_01/doc.705/e54936/cssg_create_ssl_cert.htm#CSVSG178

Answer (score 1):

It would be more prudent to add your self-signed certificate to your local JVM TrustStore.

However you can probably disable the check by creating the client object with `AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.create(URI, HttpClient)` method. It should be possible to supply your own instance of `HttpClient` to disable certificate validation. It looks like Atlassian repackaged the Apache HttpClient library with custom factories and decorators so you have to dig into `attlassian-httpclient-*` libraries source code.

There is  `com.atlassian.httpclient.api.factory.HttpClientOptions#setTrustSelfSignedCertificates(boolean)` flag. It should be possible to create own version of `AsynchronousHttpClientFactory#createClient(URI, AuthenticationHandler)` method where currently an empty `HttpClientOptions` is created:

```
public DisposableHttpClient createClient(final URI serverUri, final AuthenticationHandler authenticationHandler) {
    final HttpClientOptions options = new HttpClientOptions();
    options.setTrustSelfSignedCertificates(true); // try this
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try out the following way. Following code will skip certificate validation and use a CloseableHTTPClient instance to hit the Jira rest API

```
    private void getTicketDetails(URI url, String userid, String password)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                throws CertificateException {

        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                throws CertificateException {

        }
    } };
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
    JiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(url.getHost(), url.getPort()),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userid, password));

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
            .setSslcontext(sc).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();

    JiraRestClient client = factory.create(url, (HttpClient) httpClient);
}
```

Comment: Not having to declare checked exceptions.

Comment: Ha! Your code was fine. I was just replying to the guy that deleted his comment.

Comment: Thanks @Strelok ! There were series of exceptions that needs to be handled in this block, so thought generic catch block will do. After that felt, if OP or someone is referring to this code, it would better for them to be aware the different exceptions that needs to be handled, hence edited the code

Comment: I got a "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient cannot be cast to com.atlassian.httpclient.api.HttpClient" am i missing something?

Comment: @Sebastian yes you are correct. Just realized, attlassian has a interface with the name HTTPClient